# Print the first line of multiple files using Batch

Tags: batch-file

I've done a batch file to print the first line of multiple files using batch. But it only prints the first line of one of the files, but as many times as the number of files i have.

I mean, it does the FOR loop as many times as the number of files that I have but the variable **firstline** always have the same value.

I know I'm missing something stupid, I've been trying different combinations for hours and looking at stackoverflow entries for hours without result.

This is my code:

> for %%F in (*.trn) do set /p firstline=<%%F & echo %firstline%

Comment: Read up on Delayed Expansion, in the meantime you can quick fix it thus, `For %%A In (*.trn) Do Set/P firstline=<"%%A" & Call Echo %%firstline%%`

Comment: @Compo - if you've verified that this in fact works, propose it as an answer, not just a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The critical part that is missing is the `call` statement inside the FOR loop (yes, it was indeed something stupid). I can confirm that the "quick fix" will print the first line of each file, as requested:

```
for %%F in (*.trn) do set /p firstline=<%%F & call echo %%firstline%%
```

The suggestion about [Delayed Variable Expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is a good one. That version will look like this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%F in (*.trn) do set /p firstline=<%%F & echo !firstline!
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Compo and @Jonathan for your answers, you helped me to finish the program.

In fact, this question was a part of the program, I share the final program, maybe it's useful for someone looking for a similar solution.

I was doing a program that, if the number in the first line, of the files in a directory, is greater than 46000, it copy the file to another directory. This is the final version:

`setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
For %%A In (*.trn) Do Set/P firstline=<%%A & if !firstline! GTR 46000 move "c:\temp\number\B1\%%A" "c:\temp\number\B2\%%A"`